# How to catch AngularJS Error with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm experiencing some problem while E2E testing an AngularJS app with Protractor. To sum things up: I have the following specification and the first step always fails with a *btstrpd* error. (The page is auto-bootstrapped and we use AngularJS v1.3.0 and Protractor v2.1.0.)

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {

    it('should have a title', function() {
        browser.get('http://myapp.abc.de/ext/#/login');
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('My App');
    });

    it('should do other stuff', function() {
        // ...
    });

});
```

Error:

```
1) Protractor Demo App should have a title
 Message:
 UnknownError: unknown error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/btstrpd?p0=document
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
```

([Full description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380520/btstrpd-error-when-testing-angularjs-app-with-protractor))

Since I don't seem to find a solution to prevent this error and the remaining test steps run without any problems, my approach would be to simply ignore the error. However I don't want the test case to fail due to it. This brings me to my question: How can I catch this error so that the test won't fail? A plain try-catch around the two statements in the step does not the trick and since I don't have any promises here I also cannot do the typical promise error handling as one would manually handle e.g. a *NoSuchElementError*.

Edit - Error in webdriver console:

```
12:06:18.975 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
12:06:18.995 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3) on
port 23267
Only local connections are allowed.
12:06:21.248 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
12:06:21.271 INFO - Executing: [set script timeoutt: 11000])
12:06:21.281 INFO - Done: [set script timeoutt: 11000]
12:06:21.390 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html,<html></html>])
12:06:21.405 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html,<html></html>]
12:06:21.425 INFO - Executing: [execute script: window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRA
P!" + window.name;window.location.replace("http://myapp.abc.de/ext/#/login");, [
]])
12:06:23.440 INFO - Done: [execute script: window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!" +
 window.name;window.location.replace("http://myapp.abc.de/ext/#/login");, []]
12:06:23.458 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []
])
12:06:23.468 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]
12:06:23.489 INFO - Executing: [execute async script: try { return (function (at
tempts, asyncCallback) {
  var callback = function(args) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      asyncCallback(args);
    }, 0);
  };
  var check = function(n) {
    try {
      if (window.angular && window.angular.resumeBootstrap) {
        callback([true, null]);
      } else if (n < 1) {
        if (window.angular) {
          callback([false, 'angular never provided resumeBootstrap']);
        } else {
          callback([false, 'retries looking for angular exceeded']);
        }
      } else {
        window.setTimeout(function() {check(n - 1);}, 1000);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      callback([false, e]);
    }
  };
  check(attempts);
}).apply(this, arguments); }
catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [10]])
12:06:25.603 INFO - Done: [execute async script: try { return (function (attempt
s, asyncCallback) {
  var callback = function(args) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      asyncCallback(args);
    }, 0);
  };
  var check = function(n) {
    try {
      if (window.angular && window.angular.resumeBootstrap) {
        callback([true, null]);
      } else if (n < 1) {
        if (window.angular) {
          callback([false, 'angular never provided resumeBootstrap']);
        } else {
          callback([false, 'retries looking for angular exceeded']);
        }
      } else {
        window.setTimeout(function() {check(n - 1);}, 1000);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      callback([false, e]);
    }
  };
  check(attempts);
}).apply(this, arguments); }
catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [10]]
12:06:25.633 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return (function () {
    angular.module('protractorBaseModule_', []).
        config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
          if ($compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled) {
            $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
          }
        }]);
  }).apply(null, arguments);, []])
12:06:25.643 INFO - Done: [execute script: return (function () {
    angular.module('protractorBaseModule_', []).
        config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
          if ($compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled) {
            $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
          }
        }]);
  }).apply(null, arguments);, []]
12:06:25.663 INFO - Executing: [execute script: angular.resumeBootstrap(argument
s[0]);, [[protractorBaseModule_]]])
12:06:26.093 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: [ng:btstrpd] http://error
s.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/btstrpd?p0=document
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.134)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7
d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any
 stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'xxxxx', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.x', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: '
amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\abcdefg\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1
1436_18156}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
version=43.0.2357.134, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents
=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
 browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsE
nabled=true}]
Session ID: 0c39849d960cccef7ec7036b8414c9fb
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.
java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHa
ndler.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:599)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDri
ver.java:508)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(Even
tFiringWebDriver.java:101)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.executeScript(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.executeScript
(EventFiringWebDriver.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ExecuteScript.call(ExecuteS
cript.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession
.java:168)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
12:06:26.103 WARN - Exception: unknown error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angular
js.org/1.3.15/ng/btstrpd?p0=document
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.134)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7
d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any
 stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.x', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: '
amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\abcdefg\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1
1436_18156}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
version=43.0.2357.134, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents
=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
 browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsE
nabled=true}]
Session ID: 0c39849d960cccef7ec7036b8414c9fb
12:06:26.203 INFO - Executing: [delete session: f947352d-3b40-4b1b-a46a-9d4ffe32
8b76])
12:06:27.417 INFO - Done: [delete session: f947352d-3b40-4b1b-a46a-9d4ffe328b76]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [btstrpd Error when testing AngularJS app with Protractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380520/btstrpd-error-when-testing-angularjs-app-with-protractor)

Comment: It has the same underlying problem, but is a different question.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting on the webdriver console? That might help.

Comment: That's a good point - I added it in the description.

Comment: @Kat Have you got any update on this? I am facing the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I would put a WaitforAngular() to make sure the sync append with Angular & Protractor.  See bellow for reference:

```
it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://myapp.abc.de/ext/#/login');
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('My App');
});
```

Then if it does not work, I would use the browser.pause(); command. This will break the execution of protractor where you use the command. From there you can open the Chrome debuging console to see what is appening exactly.

You can also use the REPL debuging mode it is very convenient way to check that you element are present on the page and that you are using the correct selector.

Please refer to the following link for more informations on debugging with protractor: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/debugging